# Standard Deviations or Standard Errors for Adjusted Means in ANCOVA?

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error, ancova

I think it is standard to report standard errors (SE) for adjusted means after conducting ANCOVA. However, some people claimed it is more meaningful to provide standard deviations (SD) instead of SE. Do anyone have good arguments/references to use SE?

I really appreciate any comments.

Thank you.